# CMSs & ERPs for hospital management system

Tags: content-management-system, erp

**What are the best free CMSs or CMS plugins or ERPs or any other free tools available for developing a hospital management system?**

I want to develop it for a children's hospital run by my father. The hospital is small with two doctors. Currently, everything is done manually on paper. The main entities who will be using the system are: Receptionist, the two doctors, chemist and the medical laboratorist. They will use it majorly for keeping the records of the patient. The patients would not be interacting with the system directly. The system needs to be user friendly and should be easy to learn.
I was thinking to develop such a system using a CMS or an ERP or any other free tool. I have used wordpress/drupal in past but never used an ERP. Can you please guide me to make such a system using **free**, and preferably open source, tools?

Update: I think it will be mostly a form driven system. What would be easy and better: creating the forms in drupal or using a php framework like symphony or cakePHP?

Thanks,
Akshey

Comment: +1 for such a worthwhile cause. But I'm not sure if this is the best site for asking the question; it's certainly not the only one. If you haven't already, check out http://programmers.stackexchange.com/, http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/, and http://serverfault.com/ .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now, I have posted there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at OpenERP. It's an open source ERP written in Python with a large community and used by a lot of small and medium companies.

You can also have a look at Medical, a module for managing health and hospital information on OpenERP.

[www.openerp.com](http://www.openerp.com)

[medical.sourceforge.net](http://medical.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: You can also try a live demo here: http://medical.openerp-online.com/ (username: admin password: admin)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered OpenEMR? http://www.oemr.org/
After being tested in the ICSA Labs ONC-ATCB 2011/2012 EHR Certification Program, OpenEMR 4.1 attained Complete Ambulatory EHR Certification on August 19th, 2011, satisfying the requirements for the following criteria per the ONC Approved Test Procedures v1.1: Certified List of Features That OpenEMR Successfully Passed to Obtain Certification
This Complete EHR is 2011/2012 compliant and has been certified by an ONC-ATCB in accordance with the applicable certification criteria adopted by the Secretary of Health and Human Services.